# For TPM 1.2, using tpm-tools the tpm_sealdata does not work after a reboot

Tags: security, cryptography, embedded, tpm, trusted-computing

I am trying to encrypt and store a key in the TPM 1.2 chip and for that I am using tpm-tools package provided by TrouSerS. I can used tpm_sealdata and tpm_unsealdata when I first take ownership. But when I reboot the system, both the sealing and unsealing command no longer works giving an error: **Tspi_Context_LoadKeyByUUID failed: 0x00002020 - layer=tcs, code=0020 (32), Key not found in persistent storage**. From my understanding, the SRK (storage root key) is created when taking tpm ownership and is stored into TPM's non-volatile memory which makes it persistent. Then why am I getting this error?

I tried changing the authorization password for both owner and srk to TPM's well-know secret.
After a reboot, I can see in the BIOS that the TPM is still owned which makes me believe that SRK should be there in the persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the system.data which is created by tcsd.conf at a location /var/lib/tpm/ was not staying persistent across reboot. Making that file peristent across reboot solved the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35049589)